# Object of class Database_MySQL_Result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, kohana

views.php

```
$events = array($events); //convert $events objects to array
asort($events); //sort array in ascending order
foreach($events as $event): //iterate array
    echo $event; //getting error here
endforeach;

tried this also,

 foreach($events as $key => $event): //iterate array
     echo "$key = $event\n"; //getting error here
 endforeach;
```

I am trying to iterate the array in foreach loop but i am getting this error "`ErrorException [ Recoverable Error ]: Object of class Database_MySQL_Result could not be converted to string`"

Need help to solve this.

Comment: Try using var_dump($event) here

Comment: print_r($event); what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

$events = array($events);
This line does not convert objects to array, but it just inserts object into array;

So $events[0] equals old $events;

I don't know how you pull your data from DB, but as long as it's Kohana, maybe this would work:

$events = $events->as_array();

Answer (score 0):

try casting events as an array, instead of inserting it into array like:

`$events = (array)$events;`

this will result in all public properties on the $events object being set as an assoc array.